# Show that the sequence $(r^n)_{n\ge 1}$ does not converge if $r<-1$.

Tags: real-analysis

*** (Edited content) ***

Hi, I just came up with a clever solution and want to share with you guys!

First, note that $|a-r^n|=|a|+|r^n|$ if $a\leq 0, r^n>0$ or $a\geq 0,r^n<0$.

Given any $N$ and $a\geq 0$, I can choose  some odd positive integer $n>N$. Then, I will obtain $|a|+|r^n|\geq 1$ because $|r^n|>1$ for all $n$.

Similarly, given any $N$ and $a< 0$, I can choose  some even positive integer $n>N$ and obtain the same result.
QED.

**Question**:

i ) Show that $|r^n-r^{n+1}|\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
|r^n-r^{n+1}|
&=|(1+r)r^n|\\
&=|(1+r)||r|^n
\end{align*}

Since $|1-r|\geq 1$ and $|r|^n\geq 1^n$ for all $r\geq -1$, we have
\begin{align*}
|r^n-r^{n+1}|=|(1+r)||r|^n\geq 1\cdot 1=1
\end{align*}

ii. Use you result of i. to prove:
\begin{align*}
(\forall a\in \mathbb{R})(\forall N\in \mathbb{R})(\exists n) (n\geq N\implies |a-r^n|> \frac{1}{4}).
\end{align*}

I am currently stuck at ii.

I have tried all the tricks in the book like $|(a+r^n)-(a-r^{n-1})|$ and $||x|-|y||\leq |x -y|$ and nothing works! I would really appreciate some hints!

Answer (score 1):

If it converges to $L$, then $L$ would be finite. Take a subsequence $(r^{2n+1})_{n\ge 1}$, this sequence diverges to $-\infty$. Thus it does not converge to $L$ as supposed to. So the original sequence must diverge.

Comment: @ DeepSea The challenge is to use the definition only!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$

If $r<-1$ then $r=(-1)c$

where $c>1$ and $c^n \to +\infty$

Now $$|r^n-a| \geq ||r^n|-|a||=|(-1)^nc^n-|a||=||c^n|-|a||$$

The sequence $b_n=||c^n|-|a||$ is unbounded.

Thus for $N=1$ we can find $n_1 > 1$ such that $b_{n_1}>\frac{1}{4}$

For $N=2$ we can find $n_2 > \max\{n_1,2\}$ such that $b_{n_2}>\frac{1}{4}$

You can continue inductively for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have to admit that i do not understand why you write  $\forall N \in \mathbb{R}$

I beleive $(\forall N  \in \mathbb{N})$ is enough to prove your second statement.

We are dealing here with sequences.

Comment: @ Marios Grestsas, I think this is the answer I am looking for. Btw, is my answer on the top correct?

Comment: @chuck you have in your hypothesis that $r<-1$..thus cannot $r^n$ be positive for all $n$ or negative for all $n$,if i understood correctly your first lines

Comment: @ Marios This can be proven using induction tho.

Comment: @chuck what can be proven by induction?